# SQL - get column names when value is 1

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a junction table:

```
id | warehouse | comp1 | comp2 | comp3 | comp4
----------------------------------------------
1  | w1        |   1   |  0    |  1    |  1    => String: 'col1,col3,col4'
2  | w2        |   1   |  1    |  0    |  1    => String: 'col1,col2,col4'
3  | w3        |   0   |  1    |  0    |  0    => String: 'col2'
```

- How to get the string of column names, if the value of column is 1?

**Possible solution - change the junction table**

ommit working with column names, just work with substrings or masks 
(using `like %comp1%` for example):

```
id | warehouse| companies
-----------------------------------
1  | w1       | 'comp1,comp3,comp4'
2  | w2       | 'comp3'
3  | w3       | 'comp1,comp2,comp4'
```

Comment: Which Database you're using?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL 2008..

Comment: How many rows do you expect to have in the table? Do you want to check against all rows or a subset of rows. If so how many rows do you expect there to be in the subset of rows?

Comment: Use `CASE WHEN` to solve your issue ex `CASE WHEN column1=1 THEN 'column1'`..

Comment: @Mikael: It's ment as something like cross table (list of warehouses of several companies), and every transaction will be checked (if its warehouse exists in selected company).. it's a mess

Comment: I see the mess. Either you have warehouses or companies as column names right? If so, you probably need to refactor your tables and have a junction table between warehouses and companies.

Comment: werehouses are rows and companies are columns :-) one possible solution is to create one column named companies for example, and this column will contains the string of companies for appropraiate warehouse.. this is working, but it's a bit  nasty :-)

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate but the duplicate has almost nothing to do with what you are trying to do here. I have voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Before I can post an answer you can have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/3) to see if it does what you want.

Comment: And a bit simpler version, without the unpivot. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/4) and by the looks of it it is more effiecient.

Comment: And a version with some fancy XML query stuff that does not require you to list the column names in the query. [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/5)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly, what I've wanted!!! Please create an answer to accept it :-)

Comment: As soon as the question gets reopened.

Comment: And while I am still running with this. A dynamic version that probably will have better performance than the XML version still without the need to list the columns in the query [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/7)

Comment: Very nice, i have to understand that at first, because it started to be a bit complicated :-) But for my situation, the simplest solution is enough, because there are just 10 columns (companies) there. But it's obvious, that this last solution is more general..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is basically an `unpivot` over the column names excluded `id` and `warehouse`.

One way to do that is to use the [Table Value Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) in a sub-query that uses `for xml path('')` to build a concatenated list of column names.

```
select T1.id,
       T1.warehouse,
       stuff((
             select ','+T2.company
             from (values(T1.comp1, 'comp1'),
                         (T1.comp2, 'comp2'),
                         (T1.comp3, 'comp3'),
                         (T1.comp4, 'comp4')) as T2(value, company)
             where T2.value = 1
             for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as comp
from YourTable as T1
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/4)

The query above need to be modified when you add new columns. A query that will work with dynamic number of columns needs to be generated dynamically. You can use [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) to get the column names and build the query above dynamically and execute the query using [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx).

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)

set @SQL = '
select T1.id,
       T1.warehouse,
       stuff((
             select '',''+T2.company
             from (values'+
                           stuff((
                                 select ',(T1.'+name, ','''+name+''')'
                                 from sys.columns
                                 where object_name(object_id) = 'YourTable' and
                                       name not in ('id', 'warehouse')
                                 for xml path('')
                                 ), 1, 1, '') +
             ') as T2(value, company)
             where T2.value = 1
             for xml path('''')
            ), 1, 1, '''') as comp
from YourTable as T1'

exec (@SQL)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/7)

I was not entirely truthful when I said that this needs dynamic SQL. In this case it is actually possible to pull this off with with some xQuery stuff.

```
select id,
       warehouse,
       stuff((
             select ','+T3.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(128)')
             from T2.X.nodes('*[not(local-name() = ("id","warehouse"))]') as T3(N)
             where T3.N.value('(./text())[1] cast as xs:boolean?', 'bit') = 1
             for xml path('')
            ), 1, 1, '') as comp
from YourTable as T1
  cross apply (
              select T1.*
              for xml path(''), type
              ) as T2(X)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78bb1/5)

Building the comma separated column list is the same as in the previous queries using `for xml path('')`. Here in the cross apply there is an XML constructed for each row that is used to query the values and the element names in the sub-query. Element name corresponds to column name and is accessed using `local-name(.)`. The values for one row is unpivoted (is that even a real word) with the `nodes()` expression. `nodes()` also makes sure that `id` and `warehouse` is not returned as columns.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly, what I've looked for!

Answer (score 0):

Use case when for this.

```
select case when column1=1 then '1' else '0' end as column1 from tableName
```

Comment: Thanks, but i'm looking for something more automatic (i can have much more colums than 4)..